# How to implement jscroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Can you tell me how to implement it. I have working ajax which output divs one below other.
I called jscroll on container div but nothing happens...

$('#container').jscroll();

Answer (score 1):

Jquery

toggle

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").toggle();
});
```

or

jQuery mousedown()

```
$("div").mousedown(function(){
  $(this).after("Mouse button pressed down.");
});
```

should do but i dont know anything about jscoll have u made sure u imported the jquery library

Comment: Yes, it outputs loading text, but after I trigger ajax i still get my regular 100 results one below other with no scroll effect

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem when i started. First i updated my jquery because jscroll is supported by jquery v1.4.3+ . Thats when i got to your problem and to solve that you just define a height and overflow:auto to the container.

```
#container{ 
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The reason everything loads at once is because there is no restriction on the height.

uhmm..this is to answer the problem of 100 results all showing up at once.

Comment: This will only work in some cases, in my case, where I am using coldfusion loop to display repeated data, I must only allow so many repeated items to be shown at once.